# Unable to deploy the APP in Google Cloud App Engine Lab Task

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

I tried to working on the following lab session on Google Cloud related the App Engine app

- [App Engine Lab Session Link](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/games/4255/labs/27511)

Then in that lab session, I stuck on the **Task 3. Deploy your application**

When I tried to deploy an app, I got an error:

```
student-04-01eabe16573b@lab-setup:~/php-docs-samples/appengine/standard/helloworld$ gcloud app deploy
You are creating an app for project [qwiklabs-gcp-03-c739d1f1bcf6].
WARNING: Creating an App Engine application for a project is irreversible and the region
cannot be changed. More information about regions is at
<https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations>.

Please choose the region where you want your App Engine application located:

 [1] asia-east1    (supports standard and flexible)
 [2] asia-northeast1 (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [3] asia-south1   (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [4] asia-southeast1 (supports standard and flexible)
 [5] australia-southeast1 (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [6] europe-central2 (supports standard and flexible)
 [7] europe-west   (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [8] europe-west2  (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [9] europe-west3  (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [10] us-central    (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [11] us-east1      (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [12] us-east4      (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [13] us-west1      (supports standard and flexible)
 [14] us-west2      (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [15] us-west3      (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [16] us-west4      (supports standard and flexible and search_api)
 [17] cancel
Please enter your numeric choice:  10

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

Could someone can help for me why this is happen here ?

Comment: Have you previously run the command ```gcloud auth login```?

Comment: Which IAM roles are assigned to the account you logged in with?

Comment: I run the `gcloud auth login` command

Comment: Your last comment did not answer my question.